# Polygon of exact size in QGIS, Cartesian vs Ellipsoidal

Tags: qgis, mapping

I'd like to have a polygon representing 400x400km for Moscow and Omsk. I set the size via Advanced Digitizing toolbar. When I tried to measure the polygon, Cartesian is alright, but Ellipsoidal is off.

I tried to use ESPG:3576 and ESRI:102025, but the issue persist. The difference is bigger the more eastish the town is.

**EPSG:3576**

Moscow: Cartesian: ~400km // Ellipsoidal: ~370km

Omsk: Cartesian: ~400km // Ellipsoidal: ~600km

**ESRI: 102025**

Moscow: Cartesian: ~400km // Ellipsoidal: ~410km

Omsk: Cartesian: ~400km // Ellipsoidal: ~370km

I set the same CRS for the project (Project -> Properties), shapefile and Mapnik.

Any idea why the difference between the two measurements?

Comment: Note: It would be good to edit your question and list the projection and parameters for the two projCRS.